# Trying to change Query Table connection path wih vba for different users

Tags: excel, vba, connection

I have two excel workbooks - one is a database and the other is a tool that has two query tables in it from the database. The tool then runs off the query tables with pivots / lookups etc. Currently, operating from C drive, I have auto_open command that refreshes the query tables.
Problem - I want to place DB and Tool in dropbox online and have multiple users having their own versions of the tool that accesses the database on opening.

I can manage this having manually amended the file path for the query table but I cannot get the connection to refresh using the filepath of the user. I have looked online and tried this code variant but doesn't seem to work

```
Dim username As String
username = Environ("username")

Sheets("Table-Data").Select

Connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Dropbox\Delphy - Reports\Crop Chemical Database;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;"

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Data (13)").refresh

Sheets("Table-Setup").Select

Connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Dropbox\Delphy - Reports\Crop Chemical Database;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;"

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Setup").refresh
```

Basically - other users get a debug message on `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Data (13)").refresh`
It is not changing the connection.
What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Where are you updating the `Connectionstring`? All I can see is that you have put the connection string in a variable?

Comment: If you search stackoverflow, you will see lot of post on how to update the connection string via VBA

Comment: HI - thanks for the reply - I have looked and cannot find anything that gives me the answer I need in a way that I can apply it. I've tried but just don't seem to be able to find the right syntax.

Comment: Whilst I've set the Connectionstring to be what I want to have happen I'm missing syntax to actually insert that in the query table properties....that's the bit I just cannot get my head around.